# Closed, convex and balanced subset of a vector space

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

Let $(X,\|\ \|)$ be a vector space over $K$ and let $B\subseteq X$ be closed, convex and balanced. I want to prove the following:

> If $x_0\in X\setminus B\Rightarrow\exists\;f\in X^*$ s.t. $|f(x_0)|>c\;$ and $\;\forall x\in B\;\;|f(x)|\le c$, for some $c>0$.

What I got:

Let $x_0\in X\setminus B\Rightarrow\{x_0\}\cap B=\emptyset$ and clearly $\{x_0\}$ is compact and convex, so applying the next theorem:

> If $A,B\subseteq X$ are such that $A$ is compact and convex and B is closed and convex and $A\cap B=\emptyset$, then there $\exists\;\gamma_1,\gamma_2\in \Bbb R $ and $\exists\;F\in X^*$ s.t. $F(a)<\gamma_1<\gamma_2<F(b)\;\forall a\in A\;\forall b\in B$

I can get that there $\exists c_1,c_2\in \Bbb R$ and $\exists f\in X^*$ s.t. $\;\;f(x_0)<c_1<c_2<f(x)\;\forall x\in B$. In particular, for $x=0\in B$ I get that $f(x_0)<c_1<c_2<0\Rightarrow\;|f(x_0)|>|c_1|$ and got stucked here trying to show the other part. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Also, the field $K$ here should be the reals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $g:=-f$, where $f \in X^*$ is the functional you found. Then use that $B$ is balanced.

Comment: Sorry, I can't see how this works, I've only managed to see that:
$$
-f(-x_0)<f(x)<f(-x_0) \Rightarrow |f(x)|<f(-x_0)=:c
$$